# How to selectively split a string by removing the end characters?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a list of country names in string format as shown below:

```
AfghanistanAFG
AustraliaAUS
BangladeshBAN
EnglandENG
New ZealandNZ
ScotlandSCO
Sri LankaSL
```

(n.b. each line is a new string)

I would like to display them without the country code at the end, so just as

```
Afghanistan
Australia
```

and so on. I can think of a very unelegant solution which is to have a series of if statements to check what the first few characters of the string are and chop off the end accordingly but I wondered if there was a more elegant solution to my problem.

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: or you could just dig up the exact same information that's already properly split up/delimited, saving yourself the trouble of having to try and undo this "corruption".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive solution would be to remove the capital letters at the end of the string using a regular expression.

```
$country_name = preg_replace('/[A-Z]+$/', '', $country_string);
```

However, I agree with the comment by **Marc B**. This data is freely available. So unless you have a specific country list, I suggest pulling from the source.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list on Wikipedia with all of the sovereign states (countries)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_by_continent_%28data_file%29#Data_file

This may be easier for you to process into the data you need.